# PHP CS Fixer - Ugly indents

Tags: php

I am currently trying to setup PHP CS Fixer but the indents I am getting are far from good at the moment:

[image]

The ruleset I am using is:

```
return $config->setRules([
  '@PSR2' => true,
  'binary_operator_spaces' => [
    'operators' => [
      '='  => 'align',
      '=>' => 'align',
    ],
  ],
])
```

Any idea how to improve that?

Answer (score 2):

Solved it by setting:

```
<?php

$finder = PhpCsFixer\Finder::create()
  ->in(__DIR__ . '/src');

$config = new PhpCsFixer\Config();
return $config->setRules([
  '@PSR2' => true,
  '@PhpCsFixer' => true
])
  ->setFinder($finder);
```